# Property 'present' does not exist on type 'ModalController'

Tags: angular, ionic3

I'm trying to create a modal for a prompt in my Ionic project, but I'm getting the error in the title with this code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { EventModalPage } from '../event-modal/event-modal';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  currentEvent;
  events = [];
  today = new Date();

  constructor (
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public alertCtrl: AlertController,
    public modalCtrl: ModalController) {
              this.navCtrl = navCtrl;
              this.alertCtrl = alertCtrl;
              this.modalCtrl = modalCtrl;
    }

  onChange($event) {
    console.log($event);
    this.currentEvent = $event;
  }

  async presentEventModal() {
    const eventModal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
      component: EventModalPage
    });
    return await this.modalCtrl.present();
  }

  createEvent(date, title, duration) {
    return {
      date: date,
      title: title,
      duration: duration,
    }
  }
}
```

I'm following the official Ionic documentation that I found [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal), but for some reason I'm getting the error that the property `present` does not exist on type `ModalController`

I'm using Ionic 3.20.0 - not sure if that really matters, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `present()` on the controller, you need to be calling it on the modal like so:

```
return await eventModal.present();
```